# Update kernel modules after Spyder update

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I updated my Spyder today to Spyder 5.1, and now it keeps showing me this error message:

```
Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.1.0 and < 2.2.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.

You can install it by running in a system terminal:

conda install spyder‑kernels=2.1

or

pip install spyder‑kernels==2.1.*
```

I already tried both commands, the pip one works but I still get the error message, the conda command does not even work and shows me

```
The following packages are not available from current channels
```

Normally I use conda for all packages that are availabel on conda, so maybe someone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.1 is only available through Conda Forge at this time. Try

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge spyder-kernels=2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I've had to remove spyder-kernels from any env from any env that has it before I'm able to get it to install on any other env. I'm using conda. It seems I can't have more than one env available for use without constantly swapping where spyder-kernels is installed. This is the case for Windows 10 and MacOS. The spyder docs say to just ignore the issue - and that it was allegedly fixed by now - but I don't know how to ignore an error that makes it impossible to start a python console.

Correction: After erasing all envs and starting over from scratch (zero envs), I am now able to install spyder-kernels on multiple newly-created envs and each one functions in console without an issue.